How are Fuchsian Groups Related to the Study of Riemann Surfaces?
I am studying Riemann surfaces and recently encountered the term Fuchsian Group. I understand from Wikipedia that a Fuchsian group is a discrete subgroup of $ PSL(2, \mathbb{R}) $, specifically defined as a group $ \Gamma < PSL(2, \mathbb{R}) $ that acts properly discontinuously on the upper half-plane $ \mathbb{H} $. Formally, this means that for each $ z \in \mathbb{H} $, the orbit $ \Gamma \cdot z $ has no accumulation point in $ \mathbb{H} $.
While I have some background in Riemann surfaces, I am struggling to understand how Fuchsian groups connect to their study. Wikipedia also mentions Kleinian groups, which are discrete subgroups of $ PSL(2, \mathbb{C}) $ and act on the Riemann sphere $\widehat{\mathbb{C}} $ via Möbius transformations. However, I am unsure about the connections between Fuchsian groups, Kleinian groups, and Riemann surfaces.
Could someone help clarify how these groups are related to Riemann surfaces, and why Fuchsian groups, in particular, are relevant? Any references or explanations that provide insight into these connections would be greatly appreciated!
Context
My background includes basics of Riemann Surfaces and Complex Analysis and Group actions, but I’m new to Fuchsian and Kleinian groups.
Thank you!

How much topology do you know? For example, do you know the construction of the universal covering map over a surface? And the isomorphism between the deck transformation of that covering map and the fundamental group of the surface? If you don't know that stuff, my suggestion is go learn it and come back and ask this question later.

@LeeMosher Yes I am very much familiar with these things.

@LeeMosher I have a good grasp of Hatcher's book up to Homology Theory.

I'll limit my answer to a brief outline of the connection between Riemann surfaces and Fuchsian groups. This topic is already huge, but the topic of Kleinian groups is much huger, with connections to 3-manifold theory, and is way beyond the scope of an MSE answer.
I'll also limit my answer to the case of a Fuchsian group that acts freely on the hyperbolic plane $\mathbb H$; the other case requires orbifold theory, which is its own big ball of wax.
One overall suggestion: there's lots of good books out there on these topics. Pick one up.

Here's the brief outline.
In one direction, let a Riemann surface $S$ be given, and I'll assume that $S$ is not simply connected, so it is not the Riemann sphere $\mathbb S^2$, the complex plane $\mathbb C$, or the upper half plane $\mathbb H$. But one can lift the conformal structure from $S$ to the universal cover $\tilde S$, and now the Riemann mapping theorem tells you that $\tilde S$ is bihomorphic to $\mathbb S^2$, $\mathbb C$, or $\mathbb H$ (this is the big version of the Riemann mapping theorem, also known as the uniformization theorem). Since $S$ itself is not simply connected, the only possibilities with $\tilde S = \mathbb S^2$ or $\mathbb C$ are that $\tilde S = \mathbb C$ and $S$ is (biholomorphic to) $\mathbb C-\{0\}$ or a torus. Let's rule these cases out, equivalently let's assume that $\tilde S = \mathbb H$ in which case one says that $S$ is a hyperbolic Riemann surface.
The group $\pi_1 S$ acts as biholomorphic deck transformations on $\tilde S = \mathbb H$. The group of biholomorphic maps of $\mathbb H$ is identified with $\text{PSL}(2,\mathbb R)$ acting on $\mathbb H$ by fractional linear transformations, and so one obtains a representation $\pi_1 S \to \text{PSL}(2,\mathbb R)$. That representation acts (faithfully and) freely on $\mathbb H$ and it acts properly discontinuously, so it is an example of a Fuchsian group.
In the other direction, for any Fuchsian group $\Gamma < \text{PSL}(2,\mathbb R)$, its action on $\mathbb H$ is properly discontinuous, but we are restricting ourselves also to free actions. The map from $\mathbb H$ to the orbit space $S$ is therefore a universal covering map, and the $\Gamma$-invariant conformal structure on $\mathbb H$ descends to a conformal structure on $S$, making $S$ into a hyperbolic Riemann surface.
These two directions that I have described are inverses of each other, up biholomorphism and conjugation of $\Gamma$ by an element of $\text{PSL}(2,\mathbb R)$. So one gets a nice bijection between biholomorphism classes of hyperbolic Riemann surfaces and conjugacy classes of freely acting Fuchsian groups.

Not Riemann mapping theorem, but uniformization theorem, which is a much harder result.

I learned this all under the big umbrella of the Riemann mapping theorem. But I'll add a few words of explanation.

Yes, people frequently confuse the two, but this does not make it right.
